# TypeScript's Document interface and a browser's DOM implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I'm trying to understand, on a granular level, in which stage the actual DOM implementation of the web browser is used when using a TypeScript line like

```js
let element = document.querySelector('#someclass');
```

In Javascript `document` refers directly to the browser implementation when used within the scope of a html  tag.

In TypeScript `document` is defined in [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L19360) by

```js
declare var document: Document;
```

If the invocation of the document object above is the browser implementation', then I'm interested in how this can be considering the last declaration.

In its turn, the `Document` interface extends others:

```js
interface Document extends Node, GlobalEventHandlers, NodeSelector, DocumentEvent, ParentNode, DocumentOrShadowRoot {
 ... 
}
```

`Node` extends down to the EventTarget interface:

```js
interface EventTarget {
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    dispatchEvent(evt: Event): boolean;
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
}
```

Now, I'm extremely interested in *how* TypeScript obtains access to the actual DOM document implementation of the browser, which supplies the original DOM object via its own implementation.

If I'm completely missing the point of the TypeScript-concept of interfaces in this context, I'm also open to an elaboration on that front. But my main question relates to *how* TypeScript obtains the original DOM document object from the browser.

Comment: *"how TypeScript obtains the original DOM document object from the browser"* - it doesn't. Those interfaces are only used to make sure you're doing the right thing **at compile time**. At run time, you have regular JavaScript accessing the global `document` object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Spot on! :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you could copy your comment to an answer then my question will be marked  as *answered*.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser implements their own implementation of the spec. The spec gives somewhat precise ideas for what each dom method should do.

Take for example, [`Element.closest`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-closest).

> The closest(selectors) method, when invoked, must run these steps:
>
> 1. Let s be the result of parse a selector from selectors. [SELECTORS4]
> 2. If s is failure, throw a "SyntaxError" DOMException.
> 3. Let elements be
>      context object’s inclusive ancestors that are elements, in reverse
>      tree order.
> 4. For each element in elements, if match a selector against
>      an element, using s, element, and :scope element context object,
>      returns success, return element. [SELECTORS4]
> 5. Return null.

Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc, all write their own implementations, but the method signatures are standard. The standard is owned by some standards committee or company, this gets complicated. This is also the heart of the Google v. Oracle lawsuit.

Anyway,

The TS definition files are auto-generated from Microsoft Edge's internals. So it is not an accurate portrayal of real browsers.

Back to Element.closest. It's in the spec, but IE11 does not implement it. Gotcha.

Here is an open Github issue to ask TS to do a better job of pointing out the differences between browsers: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19183. Feel free to +1 it or whatever.